# Shared SSRS solutions with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm reasonably new to SVN. There are two of us at work that use Tortoise SVN. We have a large BI project with many reports in it that we both maintain. We can both be adding new reports or modifying different reports at the same time. We currently have the Solution and Project files under repo, but it's causing problems. If both of us add a report in same day, and one of us commits, the other then has a conflict. (I don't really have the knowledge/experience to manage conflicts yet.)

The other thing is that the solution is always showing as modified.

What's the best practice for this? Is it better just to out leave the .sln and .rptproj file out of the repository and manually add new reports to our own copies?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards

Mark

Comment: for readers who are not familiar with your business area - that is BI (business intelligence?!), SSR, which types of reports are their files(MIME-types, I ask) - texts or something else? Which (**local-specific**) data .sln may contain?

Comment: The files are all XML, but it's not feasible to merge the reports themselves. It's just the Project and Solution files I'm concerned with

Comment: Well, you **have** to merge diverged files, if you want to have reliable and consistent functional project... And XMLs are easy mergeable

Answer (score 0):

I've got a very similar issue to this.  Did anyone manage to solve it satisfactorily?
One thing that someone has suggested is to change the .rptproj file to "ignore-on-commit".. which might help.

The .rptproj file is xml and doesn't look too complex to do a compare and merge on.. not as hard as for .rdl files anyway!

More here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/DuV1EFvvCtM

I think it might help, but still not ideal.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you won't be able to "see" reports added by other users in your solution, unless you manually add them. The files will be there physically, but your solution will not laod them as part of your project.